# Streaming audio with java/spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have some files hosted in google cloud storage and I would like to stream them to a client, but the files are protected with credentials so I would like to proxy them through my java application.

So browser -> java api -> google cloud storage

What I've tried so far

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{fileId}")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> stream(@PathVariable Long fileId) throws IOException {
    logger.info("Request to stream file {}", fileId);

    //This is just a sample to for creating the input stream as it's what I get from google cloud storage
    File file = new File("./test.mp3");
    FileInputStream in = FileUtils.openInputStream(file);

    StreamingResponseBody stream = out -> {
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    };

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        //.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"")
        .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_RANGES, ACCEPT_RANGES_BYTES)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "audio/mpeg")
        .contentLength(file.length())
        .body(stream);
}
```

but this returns the whole file and displays a player (not playable though)

And when enabling CONTENT_DISPOSITION it'll create a download link for the whole file.

How can I stream audio with ranges in spring boot/plain java?

Comment: have you looked into @paul-warren's [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) project?  He's posted a few examples on how to implement for streaming audio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569561/how-to-stream-audio-with-spring-boot & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49381568/spring-mvc-how-to-stream-mp3-file-from-controller

Comment: I've seen some examples from other questions, but when I gave it a go I could not find enough resources to use it.

It supports S3 or read from file system and the whole streaming part that I struggle with is hidden inside the "file repository". Could'nt figure out a way to pass it inputstream.